# Allowing a PHP script to ssh, using sudo

Tags: apache, sudo

I need to allow a PHP script on my local web server, to SSH to another machine to perform a specified task on some files.  My `httpd` runs as `_www` with low permissions, so setting up direct passwordless SSH is difficult, not to say ill-advised.

The way I do it now is to have a minimal PHP script that sudo-exec's (as me) a shell script which is outside of the document root.  The shell script in turn calls (as me) the PHP code that does the actual SSH work, and prints its output.  Here's the code.

`read_remote_files.php` (The script I call from my browser):

```
exec('sudo -u me -n /home/me/run_php.sh /path/to/my_prog.php', $results);
print $results;
```

`/home/me/run_php.sh` (Runs as me, calls whatever it's given):

```
php $1 2>&1
```

`sudoers`:

```
_www ALL = (me) NOPASSWD: /home/me/run_php.sh
```

This all works, as my_prog.php is called as me and can SSH as me.  It seems it's not too insecure since `run_php.sh` can't be called directly from a browser (outside document root).  The issue I'm having is that `my_prog.php` isn't called as an HTTP program so doesn't have access to the HTTP environment variables (DOCUMENT_ROOT etc).

Two questions:

1. Am I making this too complicated?
2. Is there an easy way for my final script to get the HTTP variables?

Thanks!
Andy

Comment: If your server config never/rarely changes, then just hardcode the needed values into your remote script. Otherwise you'd be trying to recreate an Apache runtime environment inside your script.

Comment: using php and ssh in this way is highly unorthodox, may i ask why you are attempting to serve files in this way ?  why not use a network file system instead of SSH or a web proxy/firewall instead of PHP ?

Comment: David, yes it's certainly unorthodox! I have a lot of servers running varied tasks, and I need the flexibility of ssh to, for instance, check on running processes.  I administer everything through ssh (directly, or via Cygwin on Windows machines).  I'm using php to provide a web interface to some of the routine tasks.

Comment: Marc, that is the feeling I was getting too.  The end-tasks are not HTTP related and really the only reason I wanted them to have access to document_root was so that I could make result files available for download through the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I need to allow a PHP script on my local web server, to SSH to another machine to perform a specified task on some files."

I think that you are phrasing this in terms of a *solution* that you have difficulty in getting to work rather than a *requirement*.  Surely what you should be saying is "I want to invoke a task on machine B from a PHP script running under Apache on Machine A."  And then research solutions to this -- to which there are many from a simple 'roll-your-own' RPC tunnelled over HTTP(S) to using an XMLRPC or SOA framework.

Two caveats:

- Do a phpinfo(); on both machines to check what extensions are available and
- Also check your php.ini setting to make sure that your service provider hasn't disabled any functions that you expect to use (or do a Q&D script to `echo 'disable_functions = ' . ini_get('disable_functions') . "\n"; ...)`

If you browse here and the wider internet you'll find many examples.  [Here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-43) is one that I use for a similar purpose.

Comment: Yes, I get so caught up in getting my chosen solution implemented that I neglect to re-examine the problem.  I'll read up further.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Many systems do stuff like this using a (privileged) cron job that frequently checks for the existence of a file, a database record or some other resource, and then performs actions if there are any.

The huge advantage of this is that there is no direct interaction between the PHP script and the privileged script at all. The PHP script leaves the instructions in a resource, the privileged script fetches it. As long as the instructions can't lead to the system getting compromised or damaged, it's definitely more secure than sudoing.

The disadvantage is that you can't push changes whenever you like; you have to wait until the cron job runs again. But maybe it's an option anyway?

Comment: Thanks Pekka that is one further step of disconnection than I have taken it.  PS: I read and enjoyed your popular CSS article.